# How can you increase the shiny rate?

Tags: pokemon-series

I remember seeing somewhere that if you breed a Pokemon from a different region its offspring would have a higher chance of being shiny. Is this true?

What other methods can be used to increase the odds of obtaining shiny Pokemon?

Also, What is the chance of breeding a shiny if one/both of the parent Pokemon are also shiny?

Comment: I would use the Consecutive fishing method because you put more effort into geting a shiny pokemon So far the shinies I've gotten from this method is: - 12 Claunchers - 1 Horsea

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [serebii.net](http://www.serebii.net/games/shiny.shtml), if you breed a pokemon from another region different to your game with another pokemon, you will have a higher chance of getting a shiny pokemon. Colloquially called the *Masuda Method* after the developer Junichi Masuda, this can increase your chance of breeding a shiny from 1 in 8,192 to 1 in 2,048 (Generation 4) or 1,365.3 (Generation 5). Generation 6 figures are unknown at the moment, but to be honest I've heard a lot of people getting shinies so it could have been lowered even more.

As noted by Nolonar it is required that both parents must come from a game with different language. For instance, if your game is in English and both parents are Japanese, the Masuda method will *not* work.

---

Without any method, the chance of encountering, obtaining, or breeding a shiny pokemon is 1 in 8,192.

---

Although this doesn't specifically increase your shiny rate, there's an item called a PokeRadar which can use a method called *chaining* to find shiny pokemon in the wild. A good guide I found is [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/pokemon/comments/1ot6ex/chaining_tutorial/)

Comment: do you have know anything about the last part of my question?

Comment: @qwertyk31 Breeding shinies together does not increase your chance of getting a shiny kid. About the Masuda method, both parents must come from a game with different language. For instance, if your game is in English and both parents are Japanese, the Masuda method will **not** work.

Comment: @qwertyk31 Oops, guess I missed that bit. But yea, Nolonar answered it

Comment: Found an illustrated guide of the PokeRadar method on [Kotaku](http://kotaku.com/wanna-catch-your-pokemon-in-a-shiny-new-color-in-x-y-1450801224).

Comment: Outside of breding, there's also that rumor/theory circulating that tipping waiters and such in X and Y increases the shiny encounter rate, but it's probably best to take that with a grain of salt.

Comment: Isnt' it pretty much confirmed to be a base rate of 1 in 4096 by now? Also since we can now change the game's language, does the Masuda method work with anything with a different language? For instance, if I use a German (GER stamp) Ditto from Gen V with any English (no stamp) Pokemon I caught in my X game, will they have the higher chance even though I bought both games in Germany?

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the other region pokemon, Poke Radar, and "just breed piles of stuff" methods, there is a new [Consecutive Fishing](http://www.serebii.net/xy/fishchain.shtml) method which appears to significantly increase Shiny occurances but exists only in Generation 6/ Pokemon XY.

> It turns out that if you manage to get a chain of consecuctive fishing hooks, it will gradually increase the likelihood of finding a Shiny Pokémon, with the exact figures still to come. The higher the amount of Pokémon hooked, the more likely you get a shiny Pokémon, but as with PokéRadar, this is not a guarantee.
>
> There are a few things that will break this consecutive streak, however. If you move from the spot, the streak is broken. If you pull in the rod too early, the streak is broken. If you don't get a nibble, the streak is broken. With the latter being a possibility, it's logical to have a Pokémon with the ability Suction Cups as your lead in order to increase the likelihood of hooking a Pokémon.

[Some more info on fishing streaks is here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/696959-pokemon-x/67572859):

> What we know for sure breaks a streak:
> -Getting the "Nothing seems to be biting..." message (Random, but the odds are manipulable)
> -Getting the "No! You reeled it in too fast!" message (Pressed A too soon)
> -Getting the "No! You reeled it in too slow!" message (Pressed A too late)
> -Exiting the area in which you're fishing
> -Getting into a battle that isn't through fishing
> -Exiting the game

The shiny rate seems to increase significantly by this method and reports seem to indicate around 150-200 consecutive catches may grant a shiny. The problem of course is you can only catch shinies that can be fished up in that area, and it's mostly luck as to which pokemon you get (unless you want a shiny lucdisc or Magikarp, in which case use the Old Rod).

200 catches may seem high, but it's miles ahead of the one in 8000+ chance normally and still significantly better than the 1 in 1,365.3 chance the gen 5 foreign Ditto chance had (it is unknown if the foreign ditto method has improved in gen 6 yet).

Comment: I just managed to catch a shiny with the fishing technique, it was right around 20 successful catches in a row a shiny showed up!

Answer (score 2):

In generation II, having a shiny parent did raise the chances of hatching a shiny pokemon.

However, after gen II, the chances of a shiny are NOT increased if either of the parents of shiny. So if you're playing anything other than Gold, Crystal, or Silver, having a shiny parent won't increase the shiny rate.

Comment: For the record, since the shiny status was dependant on stats, this is technically also true for Gen I, although shinyness had no meaning there. If you trade something over to Gen II, it will become visible. This is the cause of the shiny Ditto glitch in gen II.

Answer (score 1):

With the Ultra Sun and Ultra Moon episodes, a new way of catching shiny Pokemon has also be found (only presents in these two versions): the Ultra Wormholes. This method makes it way easier to find shiny Pokemon, as a lot of people stated to have found a shiny from a few minutes until a few hours thanks to this method. There is apparently a 1% of chance of getting a shiny Pokemon this way, which is considerably high compared to the other methods.

You first need to beat the game. Then, when getting back to the [Altar of the Moone](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Altar_of_the_Moone), a warp hole should be opened here. When you get in it, you will start a mini-game consisting into navigating as far as possible through the Wormhole. For that, you have to catch as many golden globes as possible to gain speed, while dodging blue spheres and colored wormholes. If you go far enough (~3.000 light years from start), you should be able to see white wormholes with rainbow edges appearing. Getting in one of these will considerably increase the luck for the Pokemon inside of it to be shiny. The further you will go, the higher will be the chances for that Pokemon to be shiny.

A really important note is that the fact that the Pokemon is shiny or not is defined when getting out of the wormhole. It means that, if you save right before the Pokemon encounter and that this Pokemon is indeed shiny, you will be able to reset the game to try to get the desired Nature and IV while keeping the shininess. Do note that this doesn't apply to Legendaries and Ultra Beasts, for which you will have to use the regular soft reset method.

Answer (score -3):

By using this method, every 15 mins I get at least 1.

You'll need any rod (I recommend the great rod)

Have a pokemon with suction cups (Inkay, etc.)

Find an enclosed area and start fishing.

After 20 pokemon then you're getting into the shiny zone, and when you run into a shiny your chain will break.

Comment: If you have new information to add, please edit it into your previous answer rather than adding yet another answer.

Comment: Alternatively, you could make this a complete post and delete your previous one.  Dealer's choice.